# Show window temporarily in Selenium headless mode

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to automate using Selenium. The majority of the automation can be done in headless mode, so I have added this flag to make it headless:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("headless");
```

However, at certain stages it maybe necessary for the user to enter some information into the browser manually. This bit cannot be automated as the user will have to enter information specific to them. Is it possible for me to run Selenium headless, and then at a given time show the browser window for interaction? Once the user interaction has taken place, the browser should be hidden again.

Comment: This feels strange. Why do you need to manually interact with the browser?

Comment: Have you tried the answer below

Answer (score -1):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("headless");
options.AddArgument("remote-debugging-port=9222");
```

start headless browser with  `--remote-debugging-port=9222` (any port number)

Now open another chrome non headless instance and navigate to

```
http://localhost:9222
```

**Click the heighlighted link:**

[image]

**Video example:**

[image]